# How do I increase the size of arrow in mat-accordion

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular6

I'm using mat accordion and I want to increase the size of the *arrow*. 
I'm trying to increase the size using font-size and width but it's not working

currently, my `font-size:30px;`

```
<mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel>
        <mat-expansion-panel-header [expandedHeight]="'51px'">
            <mat-panel-title>
                Company Details
            </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState = true"
     (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>
                Company's Addresses Details
            </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <app-settings-addresses [linkElementDetails]="addressDetails">
        </app-settings-addresses>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Comment: Can you please share the css/scss code, which you have tried?

Comment: Please see the solution approach, if not helpful please comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach 1 :**

As `::after` property is used with selector `.mat-expansion-indicator`, you can manipulate the height and width for achieving your desired size icon.

```
.mat-expansion-indicator::after {
    height: 10px; <======== adjust accordingly
    width: 10px; <======== adjust accordingly
}
```

**Approach 2 :**

you can use `background-image` property to handle any icon from url.

```
.mat-expansion-indicator::after {
     height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-image: url(https://img.icons8.com/material/24/000000/plus.png);
    background-size: cover;
    border: none;
    border-width: 0 !important;
    transform: rotate(0) !important;
}
```

**[Demo - showing bigger icon on expansion panel (with both approaches)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/expansion-panel-icon-size-change?file=styles.scss)**

Answer (score 1):

Is the following example the same as yours? -> https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/examples

Then you can control the size of the arrows with **`padding`** (not font-size)

In the example the CSS for the arrows look like this:

```css
.mat-expansion-indicator::after {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Change the padding value to change the arrow size.

The border-width control how thick the arrow-lines are.

Comment: for some reason when I put this in my css file its not showing the changes. but it does work in the console. even afer adding `!important`. could I be missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of ::ng-deep before the selector and then play around with border-width and padding.

Also, don't forget to add !important

Your code will look like

```
/*Decreasing the arrow size*/
::ng-deep .mat-expansion-indicator::after {
  padding: 2px !important; /* decreasing inside space */ 
  border-width: 0px 1px 1px 0px !important; /* decreasing border-width */
}
```

Comment: ::ng-deep is depreciated